# Get common records between two tables based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have two tables: **IndustryCustomers** and **ProductCustomers**, they have same schema and just one column like this

IndustryCustomers:

| CustomerId |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

ProductCustomers:

| CustomerId |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

So what I want is:

1- if both industryCustomers and productCustomers have records then get common customers between them (simply by inner join on customerId)

2- if industryCustomers has any records but productCustomer has no records then select all industryCustomers

3- if industryCustomers has not any records then select all product customers

Currently I did this by using `IF` and select based on conditions, but I wonder if I can get customers by one query.

This is my query

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #IndustryCustomers)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #ProductCustomers)
        SELECT *
        FROM #IndustryCustomers ic
            JOIN #ProductCustomers pc
                ON ic.CustomerId = pc.CustomerId;
    ELSE
        SELECT *
        FROM #IndustryCustomers;
END;
ELSE
    SELECT *
    FROM #ProductCustomers;
```

Comment: So what is your question? What have *you* tried to answer the question? Why didn't those attempts work? Where are *you* stuck in completing your requirements?

Comment: The question is I want get records by one query, Currently I did that by multiple queries

Comment: it looks like you can try FULL JOIN between these two tables

Comment: That isn't a question, @SaeedEsmaeelinejad . "I want" is a request. *"Currently I did that by multiple queries"* And what are those queries? Why can't you use them?

Comment: @Sergey yes but I think it can not met condition 2 and 3

Comment: @Larnu you are right I'll update the question with what I've tried, I used query already and it works but  the query is not good I think and I'm looking for better solution

Comment: You do NOT need to use TOP within an EXISTS clause. The database engine will stop "looking" when it finds the first matching row. Learn to optimize your own code writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I probably would have utilized @Heinz's approach, but oddly enough the NOT EXISTS were performing worse than my solution. According to the execution plan, it seems the NOT EXISTS was scanning the entire table for no reason, not sure why. Will have to investigate further what is going on (I'm using SQL Server 2017 dev edition).

So here's a very succinct solution that seems to perform better than Heinzi's and Nick's solutions (in my very limited testing)

### Succinct Solution using APPLY and Full Join

```
SELECT FinalCustomerID = ISNULL(I.CustomerID,P.CustomerID)
FROM #IndustryCustomers AS I
FULL JOIN #ProductCustomers AS P
    ON I.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
     HasI = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #IndustryCustomers) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
    ,HasP = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #ProductCustomers ) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
) AS C
WHERE ('N' NOT IN (HasI,HasP) AND I.CustomerID = P.CustomerID)
    OR (HasI = 'Y' AND HasP = 'N' AND I.CustomerID IS NOT NULL)
    OR (HasI = 'N' AND HasP = 'Y' AND P.CustomerID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: In regards to performance, apparently SQL Server 2017 doesn't seem to cache the results of the non-correlated subquery so it runs for every row in the left table. This is why my solution seems to outperform the other solutions from Heinzi and Nick. For their queries, if you have 5,000 rows in #Industry and just 1 row in #Product, their query will scan #Product 5,000 times ```SELECT * FROM #IndustryCustomers WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #ProductCustomers)```

Answer (score 4):

You could `UNION ALL` your three SELECTs and put the corresponding condition in the WHERE clause, e.g.

```
SELECT ic.CustomerId 
  FROM #IndustryCustomers AS ic 
       INNER JOIN #ProductCustomers AS pc ON ic.CustomerId = pc.CustomerId
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #IndustryCustomers) 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #ProductCustomers)

UNION ALL 

SELECT ic.CustomerId 
  FROM #IndustryCustomers AS ic
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #IndustryCustomers) 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #ProductCustomers)

UNION ALL 

SELECT pc.CustomerId 
  FROM #ProductCustomers AS pc
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #IndustryCustomers)
```

Obviously, this requires all three SQLs to return the same set of columns, so I've reduced `*` to the customer id.

I do think, though, that this "solution", while formally satisfying your requirements, is less readable than your current solution...

Comment: This works too, but I don't want to do this , but thank you for offering that I didn't think about using ``UNION ALL`` and +1

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR;

```
SELECT
    *
FROM    (
    SELECT
        CustomerID  = CASE
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM ProductCustomers) THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers) THEN
                            pc.CustomerID
                        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers)
                            AND EXISTS (SELECT      * FROM ProductCustomers)
                            AND ic.CustomerID = pc.CustomerID THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                    END
    FROM    IndustryCustomers   AS ic
    FULL JOIN ProductCustomers AS pc
        ON pc.CustomerID = ic.CustomerID
) AS x
WHERE   x.CustomerID IS NOT NULL;
```

## A break down of the query

### Step 1: Get all of the data

If you want one query, but don't want to use a `UNION`, you will need to do a `FULL JOIN` of the two tables:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM    IndustryCustomers   AS ic
FULL JOIN ProductCustomers AS pc
    ON pc.CustomerID = ic.CustomerID;
```

| ic.CustomerID | pc.CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| NULL | 4 |
| 1 | NULL |

### Step 2: Filter the data in your select list based on your logic

Now you have all of the data you need to produce your desired results. Now change the columns in your results to return the results you want based on your logic. If there are no `ProductCustomers`, always return `IndustryCustomers`, if there are not `IndustryCustomers` always return `ProductCustomers`, and if both have records, only return the ones that match.

```
SELECT
    CustomerID  = CASE
                    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM ProductCustomers) THEN
                        ic.CustomerID
                    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers) THEN
                        pc.CustomerID
                    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers)
                        AND EXISTS (SELECT      * FROM ProductCustomers)
                        AND ic.CustomerID = pc.CustomerID THEN
                        ic.CustomerID
                END
FROM    IndustryCustomers   AS ic
FULL JOIN ProductCustomers AS pc
    ON pc.CustomerID = ic.CustomerID;
```

| CustomerID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| NULL |
| NULL |

### Step 3: Clean up results by removing NULLS

This gives you the results you want, but you now have NULLs for rows in the result set that don't match your criteria. You have two options for getting rid of them:

#### Option 1

Copy your `CASE` statement to your `WHERE` clause and use that to filter out `NULL`s.

**Pros:** You have one 'SELECT` statement. No real benefit here unless you just prefer the way it looks.

**Cons:** Harder to read code and if you modify this logic later, you have to remember to update the logic in both places. IMHO, the con in this one is a big con. The chances of this happening are high. I see it happen all of the time when people are making quick updates to code.

```
SELECT
    CustomerID  = CASE
                    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM ProductCustomers) THEN
                        ic.CustomerID
                    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers) THEN
                        pc.CustomerID
                    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers)
                        AND EXISTS (SELECT      * FROM ProductCustomers)
                        AND ic.CustomerID = pc.CustomerID THEN
                        ic.CustomerID
                END
FROM    IndustryCustomers   AS ic
FULL JOIN ProductCustomers AS pc
    ON pc.CustomerID = ic.CustomerID
WHERE   (CASE
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProductCustomers) THEN
                ic.CustomerID
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM IndustryCustomers) THEN
                pc.CustomerID
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM IndustryCustomers)
                AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProductCustomers )
                AND ic.CustomerID = pc.CustomerID THEN
                ic.CustomerID
        END
        )   IS NOT NULL;
```

#### Option 2

Wrap your query in a query that eliminates NULLS.

**Pros:** No duplicated logic to maintain, shorter easier to read code.

**Cons:** It's not a single `SELECT` statement, but functionally there are no cons.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM    (
    SELECT
        CustomerID  = CASE
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM ProductCustomers) THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers) THEN
                            pc.CustomerID
                        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers)
                            AND EXISTS (SELECT      * FROM ProductCustomers)
                            AND ic.CustomerID = pc.CustomerID THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                    END
    FROM    IndustryCustomers   AS ic
    FULL JOIN ProductCustomers AS pc
        ON pc.CustomerID = ic.CustomerID
) AS x
WHERE   x.CustomerID IS NOT NULL;
```

### Example code showing results for each scenario

I'm using a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and a [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to build the example data. The query that selects the data is the same in each of these.

#### `IndustryCustomers` and `ProductCustomers` both have data

```
WITH
    IndustryCustomers AS (
        SELECT
            IndustryCustomers.CustomerID
        FROM ( VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS IndustryCustomers (CustomerID)
    ),
    ProductCustomers AS (
        SELECT
            ProductCustomers.CustomerID
        FROM ( VALUES (2), (3), (4)) AS ProductCustomers (CustomerID)
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM    (
    SELECT
        CustomerID  = CASE
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM ProductCustomers) THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers) THEN
                            pc.CustomerID
                        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers)
                            AND EXISTS (SELECT      * FROM ProductCustomers)
                            AND ic.CustomerID = pc.CustomerID THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                    END
    FROM    IndustryCustomers   AS ic
    FULL JOIN ProductCustomers AS pc
        ON pc.CustomerID = ic.CustomerID
) AS x
WHERE   x.CustomerID IS NOT NULL;
```

| CustomerID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

#### `ProductCustomers` contains no data

```
WITH
    IndustryCustomers AS (
        SELECT
            IndustryCustomers.CustomerID
        FROM ( VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS IndustryCustomers (CustomerID)
    ),
    ProductCustomers AS (
        SELECT CustomerID = NULL
        WHERE 1 = 2
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM    (
    SELECT
        CustomerID  = CASE
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM ProductCustomers) THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers) THEN
                            pc.CustomerID
                        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers)
                            AND EXISTS (SELECT      * FROM ProductCustomers)
                            AND ic.CustomerID = pc.CustomerID THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                    END
    FROM    IndustryCustomers   AS ic
    FULL JOIN ProductCustomers AS pc
        ON pc.CustomerID = ic.CustomerID
) AS x
WHERE   x.CustomerID IS NOT NULL;
```

| CustomerID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

#### `IndustryCustomers` contains no data

```
WITH
    IndustryCustomers AS (
        SELECT CustomerID = NULL
        WHERE 1 = 2
    ),
    ProductCustomers AS (
        SELECT
            ProductCustomers.CustomerID
        FROM ( VALUES (2), (3), (4)) AS ProductCustomers (CustomerID)
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM    (
    SELECT
        CustomerID  = CASE
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM ProductCustomers) THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers) THEN
                            pc.CustomerID
                        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers)
                            AND EXISTS (SELECT      * FROM ProductCustomers)
                            AND ic.CustomerID = pc.CustomerID THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                    END
    FROM    IndustryCustomers   AS ic
    FULL JOIN ProductCustomers AS pc
        ON pc.CustomerID = ic.CustomerID
) AS x
WHERE   x.CustomerID IS NOT NULL;
```

| CustomerID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

## Extra notes

When using `EXISTS` clause always use the form `SELECT * FROM ...`. Not only is the intent of the code more clear, but there are no performance differences between using `*`, `1`, `TOP 1 1`, or `Column1, ..., Column327`. SQL Server stops executing the query as soon as it find a single result and never even considers the TOP. If you compare them you'll see that the execution plans are all identical.

[EXISTS (SELECT 1...) vs EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1...) Does it matter?](https://sqlitybi.com/exists-select-1-vs-exists-select-top-1-does-it-matter/)

## Test with 10,000 records in each table, and only half of them overlap

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON
DECLARE
    @IndustryStartID    int = 1,
    @IndustryEndID      int = 10,
    @ProductStartID     int = 5,
    @ProductEndID       int = 15;


WITH
    IndustryCustomers AS (
        SELECT CustomerID = @IndustryStartID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            ic.CustomerID + 1
        FROM    IndustryCustomers AS ic
        WHERE   ic.CustomerID + 1 <= @IndustryEndID
    ),
    ProductCustomers AS (
        SELECT CustomerID = @ProductStartID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            pc.CustomerID + 1
        FROM    ProductCustomers AS pc
        WHERE   pc.CustomerID + 1 <= @ProductEndID
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM    (
    SELECT
        CustomerID  = CASE
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM ProductCustomers) THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers) THEN
                            pc.CustomerID
                        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT     * FROM IndustryCustomers)
                            AND EXISTS (SELECT      * FROM ProductCustomers)
                            AND ic.CustomerID = pc.CustomerID THEN
                            ic.CustomerID
                    END
    FROM    IndustryCustomers   AS ic
    FULL JOIN ProductCustomers AS pc
        ON pc.CustomerID = ic.CustomerID
) AS x
WHERE   x.CustomerID IS NOT NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);

SET STATISTICS IO, TIME OFF
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this query has performance issues.

Comment: Performance issues? LIke?

SQL Server is smart enough to know that it only need to run the queries in the EXISTS clause once, and since they are EXISTS clauses have no criteria they should be incredibly fast. The FULL JOIN can never return more rows than the sum total of rows in both tables. So unless those two table have a huge number of records and each row has LOTS of columns, that shouldn't be a problem either. If this is the case, then you need to create an index on the CustomerID column and include any additional columns in that index that you want to return.

Comment: Yes the exist clause is fast but when use case when in select which mean it execute per row and if there is 10,000 row it will execute 10,000, by assuming impossible if exists takes 1 ms then it takes 10s to run.

Comment: Have you actually tested this? I just ran a test with the IndustryCustomer having IDs from 1-10,000 and ProductCustomers having IDs from 5,000-15,000 and it ran in a quarter of a second:    
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 204 ms,  elapsed time = 214 ms.

Comment: It's shows the JOIN as being 100% of the cost in the execution plan. You might get different results with data coming from actual tables, but it shouldn't be wildly different, but performance of a particular query is highly dependent on the specifics of the schema design, and database server environment. I've added any example showing the same query with 10,000 records in each table. It's still lightning fast.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I should test that by your last query but with your statistics it must be interesting. +1